# Flash Presentation Maker, Slides

Tags: video, flash, presentations

I'm looking for a "Flash Presentation Maker", script or software similar in functionality to the one used on this page: http://www.daptiv.com/ppmtour/index.htm

Unsure if this is the correct site for this question.

Answer (score 1):

[iSpringFree](http://www.ispringfree.com/) is pretty good.  They also have a paid version with a lot more functionality.